# Motion of a particle described by a simple differential equation

Tags: calculus, analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $X_0 = \frac12$. Let $a : \mathbb R_+ \to \{-1,0,1\}$ be a measurable function.

A particle moves in the interval $[0,1]$ as follows: $$ dX_t = a_t dt \implies X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t a_s ds$$ where the integral is the Lebesgue integral. Both $0$ and $1$ are absorbing, i.e. once $X_t$ hits $0$ or $1$ it remains there.

Suppose $a_t$ is Markovian. That is, $\exists$ a function $g: [0,1] \to \{-1,0,1\}$ such that, $a_s = g(X_s)$ for all $s$. Therefore,

$$X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t g(X_s) ds$$

I would like to claim the following:

**Claim:** $X_t$ moves only in one direction. That is, if $X_t = x >X_0$ for some $t$. Then, $\nexists s > t$ such that $X_s \in (X_0,x)$.

The reasoning is the following. Since $X_t$ reached $x$ and $a_t$ is Markovian, for any $y \in (X_0,x)$, $a(y) = 1$ (with some abuse of notation). So, it should be impossible for the particle to return back to $y$ once it moves forward.

How do I argue this formally?

Can we write the claim for when $a_t$ is everywhere Markovian?

Thanks.

Comment: What theorem do you use for the existence of a solution in the Markovian construction? Does it also provide some kind of uniqueness?

Comment: What does "absorbing" mean in the first formulation? In the second, does it only mean $g(0)=g(1)=0$ or is there some behavior in the neighborhood involved? Are explicit Euler results valid approximations for a solution?

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for the comment. As you can guess, I don't know enough about the theory behind the solutions to such equations. I have modified the question a bit to say that, assuming that there is a Markovian solution, can we get the result I want. 

On the second question, absorbing means, once $X_t$ hits $1$ or $0$ it remains there.

Comment: It is still not clear what a solution is. If $g$ would only have a finite number of jump points, then candidates for solutions would be piecewise linear functions. But their derivative is not defined everywhere. So you would have to work with some generalized derivative concept, which in any case make the solution non-unique. However, what to think about the case where both of $g^{-1}(\pm 1)$ are dense subsets?

Comment: What you are asking is a very valid question. But, the order in which I am doing this is by first having a measurable process $a_t$ and then constructing a $g(\cdot)$ function based on it. That is, if $a$ is Markovian, it means there is a "good" $g(\cdot)$ associated with it. So, starting with a $g$ such that $g^{-1}(\pm 1)$ is dense would not be admissible. 

To give a broader context, this question comes from a theory of optimal control where we often go from controls of the form $a_t$ to feedback controls that depend only on the position $X_t$.